# Magento 2.3.1 clear carts and start over

Tags: database, magento2.3, shopping-cart

I want to clear all shopping carts from database and start from scratch. But I don't want to create problems in database for my customer accounts or store orders.
I just want to remove all carts which are abandoned.

I am thinking to use this queries in database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Will these do my job? Or I break everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together an extension which deletes old quotes

https://github.com/DominicWatts/QuoteCleaner

Can trigger through console or let magento cron task handle it

crontab.xml

`https://crontab.guru/#*/25_*_*_*_*`

Comment: **Dominic** great extension!! Tell me something....I see cron folder. So you don't have to run the script. Just to configure settings in admin,right?

Comment: You can either run it manually or let magento cron task handle it. I set it at every 25th minute https://crontab.guru/#*/25_*_*_*_* but you can edit crontab.xml to do what you want. I just chose something at random.

Comment: Great Job!!! Thank you!....I am also checking your repositories.....It is very good to have people like you in this community

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use this query:

```
DELETE FROM quote WHERE quote.is_active = 1;
```

This query will delete only the active quotes (abandoned carts). This query will also delete related information in other `quote.*` tables thanks to "ON DELETE CASCADE" option.

Inactive quotes (with is_active = 0) are, usually, carts that have been converted to orders.

Comment: to understand if I also run `DELETE FROM quote WHERE quote.is_active = 0;` will also remove the inactive carts? I want to clear all carts.